# File Explorer lag/crash while deleting/modify .ogg files within nested folders

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I'm on Windows 10 (WX).
Pretty beefy gaming PC. (Skip to bottom)

So within a very deep file directory `(C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\A Game\assets\mods\FastAttacks\assets\media\sound\battle\special)`

I've got a number of audio files in there. That's it.

When I try to modify them by dragging audio files from a different file into there so as to update my mod, it takes *FOREVER.* And when I say forever I mean it might eventually let me drag files in to replace things or maybe not. 
[image]

Pretty much is stuck on this ad infinium.

This is highly irregular and was wondering if... I dunno, I have a virus? No idea. Defrag? I had 4.5GB free in my C:\ at that time and thought maybe that's the issue and have deleted a few things since then. But regardless I'm sure you see my point and I doubt that 4 GB would truly be the issue.

On one occasion this caused file explorer to crash when I tried to intervene.

Long story short those files are untouchable, even with regular deletion. If I really wanted to be rid of them I could, sure, like use CMD I guess, but this is just more like... what is going on?

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Skip to here
It looks like changing file names is causing a problem no matter what! Or the problem is not limited to .ogg's.

Thanks!

Comment: If you aren't getting an actual ERROR, I myself would guess that you have a third party shell extension getting into the mix here.  When you do something in the explorer, the extension handlers at that level need to assemble the path using things called [PIDL](https://www.zabkat.com/2xExplorer/shellFAQ/bg_shell.html)s which represent your file path.  EVERY extension will iterate over this list with good or crappy code (you don't know) to get to the solution.  I would suggest [neutering your shell extensions](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) before digging deeper.

Comment: I don't fully understand you, however I do have wox and everything. Would either of those two possibly be what you're talking about?

Oh no. This is not good. I just tried to edit the name of a .ogg audio file on my *desktop* and windows xplorer has just started to hang.

Comment: Try the tool I [pointed you at](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).  TEMPORARILY disable the non Microsoft extensions to troubleshoot.  Yes, Wox *could be* the problem.  I haven't looked at its source code.  I myself would strip EVERYTHING and add it back a little at a time to determine who is causing the problem.. .. OR ... I would use the process monitor and see what the explorer is actually doing but that takes a lot to learn.  You will be fine :) .. s**t locks up sometimes.  Just [CTRL]-[SHIFT]-[ESC] kill the explorer and fire it back up until you figure out the problem.

Comment: Oh.. and if you still don't understand, I will try to elaborate further.. but it is getting close to my bedtime. :)

Comment: Sure. Thanks. So I've downloaded that thing, and there are a LOT of items. I did my best to disable anything that LOOKED like it wasn't windows but really no guarantee. Probably wasn't perfect. I tried to then change a file's name. No luck. Same crash. In process monitor I tried to change something's name and took a glance. I don't understand process monitor too well but saw many entries by scvhost of the result: name not found and the detail said desired access: read. Saw one or two buffer overflows by scvhost

Going to boot into safe mode and come back. Getting a bit worried now

Comment: Well Sgt.  .. The explorer needs to be restarted after disabling items.  Otherwise, you have done nothing.  The extensions are still running.  You can use the process explorer tool and look at DLLs loaded to see what ones.. this is another way of loooking.  ~SPC4 CMasmas.  You can use the method I describe above to kill and restart all instances of explorer.exe.  There are better ways, but that one will work.

Comment: Whoops! Ok will try that. brb

Comment: The process monitor can not be read by mere humans like you and I.  There is too much information PERIOD.  You need to learn how to filter for what you are looking for.  For starters, "processname -> contains -> explorer".  Programs look for crap that isn't there A LOT and these will show as errors.. but they aren't.  Try to ignore svchost unless you MUST.

Comment: When a windows program queries something (like a path or registry key), a good programmer will call in once to get the size with a 0 sized buffer.  They allocate the buffer needed and read back in.  Buffer overflow will occur EVERY TIME this happens (which is legit and ok).

Comment: Apparently I'm unable to move this to a chat. But anyway. I disabled EVERYTHING not microsoft by hiding all MS extensions in ShellEx View, ctrl A and disabled. Still happened.
BUT. Earlier, before I booted into safe mode I don't know what caused this but I was able to change a file name's extension with no problem. A little while after disabling all of this, same thing happened again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the issue of Explorer crashing when renaming or deleting a .ogg file, uninstall the Web Media Extension package.

Click Start, Settings, Apps, Apps & features.
Scroll down the list, select Web Media Extensions, and click Uninstall.

[image]

*Src: [Can't Rename or Delete OGG file; Explorer Crashes](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/cant-rename-delete-ogg-file-crashes-explorer/)*

Comment: HOly ***@ that's unreal. I think you fixed it. I didn't think the issue was limited to .ogg's. I believe it was the web media extensions. This is nuts.

This did not occur when I was in safe mode.

Thanks. WTf microsoft. This is unbelievable.

Comment: Thanks a ton I can't even give you +1.

Comment: Freaking amazing @w32sh .. +1 .. your name reminds me of [win32s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32s).

Comment: Thank you @SgtStacker for the feedback.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas: Win32Sh.. short for Win32Shell. Been using Windows since 3.1 never heard of Win32s. thank you for telling me about Win32s. :-)

Comment: Saved my life. I thought I am going crazy with that bug.